# Cannot send jQuery ajax() request to php

Tags: php, jquery

I have a trouble in using ajax() function. I have an html file with a form and have a segment of JavaScript code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(){
                var url = "xxx.php/";
                var param = $("#streetInput").serialize() + "&";
                    param += $("#cityInput").serialize() + "&";
                    param += $("#stateInput").serialize();

                    htmlobj = $.ajax({
                                     url: url, 
                                     data: param, 
                                     type: 'GET',
                                     dataType: 'JSON',
                                     success: function(output) {
                                         // parse the data here
                                     },
                                     error: function() {
                                     }
                                    });
              });

        });
    </script>
```

I want construct an URL pointing to a specified php file by GET method. However, I don't know how to retrieve the parameters sent through URL in xxx.php file. I don't know how to debug. I just type

```
<?php
    echo $_GET("streetInput");
    echo $_GET("cityInput");
    ......
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
?>
```

but it didn't work. Can someone help me out? I want to give three parameters through URL to  xxx.php, then print those elements

In xxx.php file, I construct a URL for an API request and get an XML file back. And I want to convert the $xml file to JSON format and return to my html file.

Comment: `echo $_GET` and see what happens.

Comment: Try using $_GET['streetInput'] instead.

Comment: instead of `serialize` each input, why don't use `serialize` on form itself?

Comment: can you show me your code detail? form-html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your JS code to:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(){
                var url = "xxx.php";
                var param = $("#streetInput").serialize() + "&";
                    param += $("#cityInput").serialize() + "&";
                    param += $("#stateInput").serialize();

                    $.ajax({url: url, data: param, type: 'GET'});
            });

        });
</script>
```

Or, if you have only these fields in form, use this:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(){
                var url = "xxx.php";
                var param = $(this).serializeArray(); //<- Or, .serialize() can also be used

                $.ajax({url: url, data: param, type: 'GET'});
            });

        });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. By the way, if I have a JSON type data in xxx.php, how can I transfer it back? The whole process of the website is like following: type an Address and use GET method to send to xxx.php, then xxx.php can use those parameters to rebuild some data and transfer back the rebuilt data.

Comment: Then you can use `success` callback to capture that response. Add this in your question & I will add the solution for that also.

Comment: Can you help me with another problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26618374/pass-json-from-php-to-ajax