# Pass JSON from PHP to ajax()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax():

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function(){
                var url = "xxx.php/";
                var param = $("#streetInput").serialize() + "&";
                    param += $("#cityInput").serialize() + "&";
                    param += $("#stateInput").serialize();

                    $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            data: param,
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(data) {
                                // parse the data here
                                alert(data);
                            },
                            error: function(){
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        });
            });

        });
</script>
```

And I successfully pass parameters to xxx.php file, and also convert some data to JSON form and echo them correctly.

```
<?php
$streetArr = array(); $cityArr = array();
$street = $city = $state = "";
$url = 'http://www.zillow.com/webservice/GetDeepSearchResults.htm?zws-id=myid&';


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
{

    $street = test_input($_GET["streetInput"]);
    $city = test_input($_GET["cityInput"]);
    $state = test_input($_GET["stateInput"]);
    $streetArr = strsToArray($street);
    $cityArr = strsToArray($city);

    $url = $url . "address=" . $streetArr[0];
    for($x = 1; $x < count($streetArr); $x++)
        if($streetArr[$x] != "#")
            $url .= "+$streetArr[$x]";

    $url = $url . "&citystatezip=" . $cityArr[0];
    for($x = 1; $x < count($cityArr); $x++)
        $url .= "+$cityArr[$x]";

    $url = $url . "%2C+" . $state . "&rentzestimate=true";

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
    echo json_encode($xml);

    ..... // some functions
}
```

but when I debug on Firefox with Firebug, I cannot get "alert(data)" but "alert("error")" instead. I don't know why my ajax() request not success.

I get the JSON data in server-side:

```
{"request":{"address":"2636 Menlo Street","citystatezip":"Los Angeles, CA"},"message":{"text":"Request successfully processed","code":"0"},"response":{"results":{"result":{"zpid":"20593083","links":{"homedetails":"http:\/\/www.zillow.com\/homedetails\/2636-Menlo-Ave-Los-Angeles-CA-90007\/20593083_zpid\/","graphsanddata":"http:\/\/www.zillow.com\/homedetails\/2636-Menlo-Ave-Los-Angeles-CA-90007\/20593083_zpid\/#charts-and-data","mapthishome":"http:\/\/www.zillow.com\/homes\/20593083_zpid\/","comparables":"http:\/\/www.zillow.com\/homes\/comps\/20593083_zpid\/"},"address":{"street":"2636 Menlo Ave","zipcode":"90007","city":"Los Angeles","state":"CA","latitude":"34.03163","longitude":"-118.289972"},"FIPScounty":"6037","useCode":"Duplex","taxAssessmentYear":"2013","taxAssessment":"152082.0","yearBuilt":"1924","lotSizeSqFt":"5242","finishedSqFt":"1728","bathrooms":"2.0","bedrooms":"2","lastSoldDate":"07\/29\/1996","lastSoldPrice":"115000","zestimate":{"amount":"452915","last-updated":"10\/26\/2014","oneWeekChange":{"@attributes":{"deprecated":"true"}},"valueChange":"3507","valuationRange":{"low":"375919","high":"520852"},"percentile":"0"},"rentzestimate":{"amount":"1887","last-updated":"10\/27\/2014","oneWeekChange":{"@attributes":{"deprecated":"true"}},"valueChange":"-9","valuationRange":{"low":"1415","high":"2680"}},"localRealEstate":{"region":{"@attributes":{"id":"268581","type":"neighborhood","name":"West Adams"},"links":{"overview":"http:\/\/www.zillow.com\/local-info\/CA-Los-Angeles\/West-Adams\/r_268581\/","forSaleByOwner":"http:\/\/www.zillow.com\/west-adams-los-angeles-ca\/fsbo\/","forSale":"http:\/\/www.zillow.com\/west-adams-los-angeles-ca\/"}}}}}}}
```

After I click submit button, then it shows alert("error") first and then redirect to xxx.php as I specified in

Comment: I'm not sure, but shouldn't the `param` var be `data`?

Comment: This seems like you have an error in your php which is causing your script to return something other than a 200 response. Can you post your php code?

Comment: Also, I recommend looking at this: http://blog.bcdsoftware.com/2323/how-to-use-chrome-developer-tools-to-debug-ajax/

Comment: No, they are different. the data in success function should be whatever be print or echo in server-side. But I just don't know why I successfully echo in server-side but the ajax() query is error

Comment: Inspect the request itself in browser console for clues. Also use the arguments of error callback to get more information about the error.

Comment: Please also post what are you getting in `$xml`.

Comment: I displayed the JSON data on server-side, and also found a strange thing as describe above.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the content type in the header at the PHP code and you mustn't print anything except the json_encoded data

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Answer (score 0):

> dataType: 'json',

Will specifically look for content type to be json and you can only parse the response when the data type is real json.

Like xrissz pointed out, you will need to set your content type with

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and it should be placed before you echo/give any output from your script, usually at the top of your script.